# How to get the list of the account details using google my business api?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-my-business-api

I am trying to list down all the accounts that have given access to manage their account. but when I am using  https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts then it shows (error 1) and when i am using access token then it gives the details of the user's account but i wanted to list down all the accounts. but i don't know how can I do this.
when i am sending the request on /accounts it with my client id as a bearer token and when i am trying to send using no auth then it gives this error

> Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=authorize"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>prac</h2>
    <div
      id="g_id_onload"
      data-client_id="xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
    ></div>
    <script>
      function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
        const config = {
          scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage",
          client_id: "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        };
        var requestOptions = {
          method: "GET",
          redirect: "follow",
        };

        fetch("https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts", requestOptions)
          .then((response) => response.text())
          .then((result) => console.log(result))
          .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
        gapi.auth2.authorize(config, function (response) {
          var requestOptions = {
            method: "GET",
            redirect: "follow",
          };
          console.log(response.access_token);
          fetch(
            `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts?access_token=${response.access_token}`,
            requestOptions
          )
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((result) => console.log(result))
            .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: @DaImTo i have added the code please suggest any solution if possible

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/google/google-my-business-samples/blob/master/java/AccountsList.java
here you can find your answer, the result is a JSONObject and you can parse it.
remember to include your client_secrets.json file in the project folder